# DotNetNuke Custom Module Development using Chris Hammond's Templates Error

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I am working on a custom module for Dot Net Nuke and am currently just setting up my environment. I have it pretty much completed however every time I try to export and use the default templates provided by Chris Hammond I also get an error with the module.

It always comes back with :

"
Error: EmployerPortalManager is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) at PetaPoco.Database.CommonConstruct() at PetaPoco.Database..ctor(String connectionStringName) at DotNetNuke.Data.DataContext.Instance() at UBA.Modules.EmployerPortalManager.Components.ItemController.GetItems(Int32 moduleId) in c:\websites\vmotest02\DesktopModules\EmployerPortalManager\Components\ItemController.cs:line 46 at UBA.Modules.EmployerPortalManager.View.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\websites\vmotest02\DesktopModules\EmployerPortalManager\View.ascx.cs:line 45 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
"

Any ideas on how to go about solving this problem? I am using DNN 07.02.02 (303) and VS 2012 with the 2.5 templates in C#.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "export" are you meaning when you try to build in Release mode?

Comment: Any response to my inquiry?

Comment: Sorry about that, work is busy these days.

I figured out the issue. My instance of DNN was based upon a backup of a site that had a lot of custom work in OWS. Therefore when I removed the OWS module's from the pages I had the template isntalled too, the conflicts resolved and I was able to develop on the instance. Unsure exactly the cause, however I unfortunately probably won't be able to go back in time to re-create/fix this issue as of the current foreseen future. So my tip is if this error occurs, and you use OWS, to remote the OWS module. 

Your template works great by the way.